# Get full text shown in TDengine database query result

Tags: tdengine

I want to see the create database sql and I use `show create database test` command. But the result is [image]
I want to see the whole information about Create Database column, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

use
show create database test\G;
or
set max_binary_display_width 200;